# SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

I set up shellinabox on my linux box to access my PC from work and registered a domain name (goofy as in developer_forums so as to fool the admins) but there is one little loophole the https site (my pc) does not have an SSL certificate. How can i fix that ?

Comment: You can generate a self-signed ssl certificate (google for it, there's plenty of tutorials - you are using Apache I presume?); however, I'd go through a simpler route: run a SSH server on port 443. Shell access, and it can proxy your web access too.

Comment: no client like putty or a linux box is available at the office :(

Comment: Putty is a stand alone program that requires no installation.  Unless your incredibly heavily locked down you should be able bring it in on a flash drive and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind people will generate you a free ssl certificate and provide installation instructions

http://www.startssl.com/

That said I agree with what was suggested in your comments, ssh would be a better, safer and easier way to get the same result.